# How render cached component of React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm developing a system using React/Redux.

I want to use cached component to respond customer request.

```
window.CacheHolder = new Map()
export default class TestComponent extends Component {  
    constructor(props) {  
        super(props)  
    }  

    componentWillUnMount(){    
        // to cache this component.  
        window.CacheHolder.set('TestComponent', this);
    }  

    render() {  
        const cachedComponent = window.CacheHolder.get('TestComponent')  
        if (cachedComponent) {  
            return cachedComponent  
        }  
        return ...   
    }  
}
```

of course, this way doesn't work.
Does anyone know other way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why? You may be able to re-render the component with same state, especially since you're using Redux. You possibly have XY problem.

Comment: it's just as you say. i need to set the state of each items, then i have to add the state to Store.Thanks!

Comment: you should try to cache the state, not the component itself. React will render the same UI for the same state.

Answer (score 0):

Use stateless components and keep you component state in redux store. Then you can sync the state with localStorage [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist), this way you'll be able to recover user state even after application is re-loaded.